# osrmTable give incorrect results when two latitudes or longitudes are identical

Tags: r, coordinates, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude, osrm

I am trying to use `osrmTable` to calculate driving distances, but I am encountering incorrect results under certain circumstances. It took me a lot of trial and error to (I think) identify when the error happens, but I think I have figured it out (though not the solution) - see below. First, say we have the following data and run `osrmTable` (using the demo server):

```
library(osrm)
library(sf)
a <- data.frame(
    lon=c(-98,-92),
    lat=c(38,38))

b <- data.frame(
    lon=c(-68,-109),
    lat=c(38,34))

a <- st_as_sf(a, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84")
b <- st_as_sf(b, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84")

osrmTable(src = a, dst = b, measure=c("duration", "distance"))
```

This produces:

```
$durations
  1 2
1 0 0
2 0 0

$distances
  1 2
1 0 0
2 0 0

$sources
        lon      lat
1 -9.497727 38.78069
2 -9.497727 38.78069

$destinations
        lon      lat
1 -9.497727 38.78069
2 -9.497727 38.78069
```

This is nonsensical - the durations and distances are all 0, and the sources and destinations are nowhere remotely close to the actual ones.

But if I then make only one very small change - instead of the `lat` being both 38, I change the second to be 38.01 - I get correct (and dramatically different) results.

```
c <- data.frame(
    lon=c(-98,-92),
    lat=c(38,38.01))

d <- data.frame(
    lon=c(-68,-109),
    lat=c(38,34))

c <- st_as_sf(c, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84")
d <- st_as_sf(d, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = "WGS84")

osrmTable(src = c, dst = d, measure=c("duration", "distance"))
```

Results:

```
$durations
       1      2
1 2078.6  971.8
2 1732.5 1319.3

$distances
        1       2
1 2769379 1236686
2 2250736 1829854

$sources
        lon      lat
1 -98.00000 37.99923
2 -92.00317 38.01000

$destinations
         lon      lat
1  -69.97288 41.24970
2 -108.99029 33.99603
```

These results make sense. Again, the only thing that changed was that I made the latitudes slightly different in the `a` data frame.

What is causing this odd behavior, and is there a way to achieve correct results besides changing the coordinates to be slightly different?

Comment: Hi! Did you raise an issue at the github page of osrm? https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/issues

Comment: I don't think I have done that. Should I?

Comment: It might be a good idea so you can get an official answer from the maintainers of the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Your lat/lon is being converted to an incorrect polyline

Your latitude and longitude are converted to an incorrect [polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) representation. This seems to be caused by an older version of the `googlePolylines` package, which is imported by `osrm`. This can be fixed by downloading the development version of `osrm` and updating all dependencies.

### Source of the problem

This `osrmTable()` function builds a url that it sends to a server running the [osrm backend](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend), a high-performance routing engine written in C++, and parses the json response for you.

My initial question was: is your problem caused by sending the server the wrong request, or by the server itself?

To find out, let's try your `osrmTable()` call using one pair of coordinates, the first row of `a` and the first row of `b`:

```r
res_table <- osrmTable(src = a[1, ], dst = b[1, ], measure = c("duration", "distance"))
```

The magic happens on [line 107](https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/blob/master/R/osrmTable.R#L107) of the `osrmTable()` source:

```r
url <- paste0(url, encode_coords(x = loc, osrm.server = osrm.server), "?")
```

In your case, the url generated is `https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-car/table/v1/driving/polyline(_%7B%7CfF~rcuQ?_kbvD)?sources=0&destinations=1`. We can decode that polyline in R:

```r
googlePolylines::decode("_%7B%7CfF~rcuQ?_kbvD")
#        lat       lon
# 1  0.00096   0.00012
# 2  0.00094   0.00015
# 3  0.00106   0.00017
# 4 -0.00010 -97.99982
# 5 -0.00010 -67.99982
```

These are not close to the coordinates that you entered. The problem is on our end - we are sending the server the incorrect coordinates.

### How to fix the problem

Install the development version of `osrm`:

```r
remotes::install_github("riatelab/osrm")
```

If prompted, update other packaging dependencies, most importantly `googlePolylines`. Your versions should be at least:

```r
packageVersion("osrm") # 4.0.1
packageVersion("googlePolylines") # 0.8.2
```

We can then simulate what happens in the [`osrm::enable_coords()`](https://github.com/riatelab/osrm/blob/master/R/utils.R#L258) function. Note that in the updated version, it no longer generates a polyline if the osrm server is the default (`https://routing.openstreetmap.de/`), so I have set it to something else for testing:

```r
# Create your previous coordinates
loc <- data.frame(id = 1, lon = c(-98, -68), lat = c(38, 38))
osrm:::encode_coords(x = loc, osrm.server = "some_random_server")
# "polyline(_{|fF~rcuQ?_kbvD)"
```

The polyline is different. If we convert it back we get:

```r
googlePolylines::decode("_{|fF~rcuQ?_kbvD")
#   lat lon
# 1  38 -98
# 2  38 -68
```

This means your original request should now work as intended:

```r
osrmTable(src = a, dst = b, measure=c("duration", "distance"))

# $durations
#        1      2
# 1 2078.6  971.8
# 2 1735.8 1322.7

# $distances
#         1       2
# 1 2769379 1236686
# 2 2252086 1831203

# $sources
#        lon      lat
# 1 -98.0000 37.99923
# 2 -91.9997 38.00023

# $destinations
#          lon      lat
# 1  -69.97288 41.24970
# 2 -108.99029 33.99603
```

We can compare this output to your second case, where you manually changed the input by 0.01. It is, as expected, almost identical.